# CORS on AWS Elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, cors, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to AWS and used

- **Elastic beanstalk** to deploy my rest API (api.example.com) in node
- and **S3 bucket** with **cloudfront** for my static website (example.com) in React.

When calling the API endpoints from website, the browser is giving the CORS error. How can i prevent that?

I'm using following code in the node project for CORS

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
  next();
});
```

**Edit** - based on arudzinska's comment

I also configured CORS in the bucket

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

> and the server is on **nginx**

Thanks in advance for any help

> P.S - also, i have seen that few posts gives the reason as there would be some bug in the project code but all the endpoints are working correctly on [**POSTMAN**](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Comment: Did you configure CORS also on your bucket?

Comment: yes i did that in the bucket, please see the updated question

Comment: Did you find a solution @Aman?

Comment: Please check my answer @ZeferiniX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated the CORS configuration in AWS to and it worked

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: i'm having the same problem. where do i find this file exactly?

Comment: @RZKY Go to S3 -> Your Bucket -> Permissions -> CORS Configuration

Comment: Neither is working for me, tried adding configurations & add app.use(cors())